# Given series diverges or converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given:

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac2{7*i + 21} $$

The limit of the $nth$ term is 0, it means we aren't sure if it diverges.

On [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+2+%2F+(7n+%2B+21),+n%3D1+to+infinity) it says it diverges by comparison test, but how?

Comment: The [Harmonic Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) diverges.

Comment: Compare with harmonic series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $i\ge1$ we have
$$\frac2{7i+21}\ge\frac2{7i+21i}=\frac1{14}\frac1i\ .$$
We know that
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac1i$$
diverges, therefore
$$\frac1{14}\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac1i$$
diverges, therefore... can you finish this?